# NodeJs:MongoDB: I want to obtain the date from an ISODate without the time using aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Currently I have a date with the time. I want one with out it. I am using aggregate  to do this

```
InvoiceDate:{$date:{"$header.InvoiceDate"}},
...
```

that is the line I am trying to use just to get the date and ignore the time; however, it isn't working.

Edit:I want it in the form yyyy-dd-mm

Comment: You can use [$dateFromParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToParts/) in 3.6. Something like `InvoiceDate:{$dateFromParts:{
     year:{$year:"$header.InvoiceDate"},
     month:{$month:"$header.InvoiceDate"},
     day:{$dayOfMonth:"$header.InvoiceDate"}
}}`. This will set all the time components to 0.

Comment: yes it does remove the time but I want to remove the time completely so it doesn't display at all in my collection.

Comment: okay. Try `InvoiceDate: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$header.InvoiceDate" } }`

Comment: Sorry i forgot to specify that I want it in date form as well, so if I were to run a script on my database later that dealt with date I would be able to not have to convert it back into a date. Is there anyway for me to do what I am asking or no? Thank you though.